# PDF of non independent random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence, poisson-distribution

I have the following probabiliy problem: Let  be a random variable with a Poisson distribution with parameter , where  is a random variable with a Poisson distribution with parameter .
• Determine the PDF function of  + .

My question is how can I find the PDF if the distributions are not independent?

Comment: check https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21549/how-to-add-two-dependent-random-variables

Comment: You are given $X\mid Y=y\sim \text{Poisson}(y)$ where $Y\sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$. So you have information regarding the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$, which is all that is needed for the distribution of $X+Y$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Do you disagree with Sergio?

Comment: @Sergio but in that post there's not really another relationship between $A$ and $B$?

Comment: i guess step 1 is to get joint distribution which is here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Conditional_continuous_distributions --> [image](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/b2e16052d580d418e683bb220a41c2c895227945). then there's step 2: get pdf of sum given joint pdf